# How can I compare system_clock::now() to a local time in c++20?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++20

I am testing a library like follows:

```cpp
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point FromDateTime(const DateTime& dateTime)
{
    std::tm tm{};
    tm.tm_year = dateTime.Year - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = dateTime.Month - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = dateTime.Day;
    tm.tm_hour = dateTime.Hour;
    tm.tm_min = dateTime.Minute;
    tm.tm_sec = dateTime.Second;

    const auto& time = std::mktime(&tm);
    const auto& timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time);

    return timePoint;
}

TEST_F(MyLibraryFixture, GetDateTime)
{
    // Arrange
    const auto& now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // Act
    const auto& actual = _testee->GetDateTime();

    // Assert
    const auto& timeDiscrepanceInSec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(FromDateTime(actual) - now);
    ASSERT_TRUE(timeDiscrepanceInSec.count() < 10);
}
```

The `DateTime` type is just a raw struct with the above used fields. The call

```cpp
_testee->GetDateTime();
```

gives a `DateTime` struct back and the date time is actually *local time*. For some reason inherent to the library I am testing, I need to compare the *local time* with the time it is *now*. My code above seems to be working fine, I "hope" it will still work when we get back to Summer time.

Now, c++20 exposes a lot of date time utilities. I have browsed the documentation, I have tried some stuff, but I was not able to come up with a reliable counterpart to the above snippet. Is it any possible (I mean, without using `std::mktime` and the strange `std::tm`)?

The closest I was able to come is this, but it is still wrong (I get a discrepancy of one hour):

```cpp
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::local_t, std::chrono::seconds> FromDateTime(const DateTime& dateTime)
{
    const auto& d = std::chrono::year_month_day(std::chrono::year(dateTime.Year), std::chrono::month(dateTime.Month), std::chrono::day(dateTime.Day));
    const auto& t = std::chrono::hours(dateTime.Hour) + std::chrono::minutes(dateTime.Minute) + std::chrono::seconds(dateTime.Second);
    const auto& dt = std::chrono::local_days(d) + t;

    return dt;
}

TEST_F(MyLibraryFixture, GetDateTime)
{
    // Arrange
    const auto& now = std::chrono::utc_clock::now();

    // Act
    const auto& actual = _testee->GetDateTime();

    // Assert
    const auto& timeDiscrepanceInSec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(FromDateTime(actual).time_since_epoch() - now.time_since_epoch());
    ASSERT_TRUE(timeDiscrepanceInSec.count() < 10);
}
```

Comment: I would recommand Howard Hinnant's library - https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/current_zone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the equivalent C++20 code to your first version of `FromDateTime`:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
FromDateTime(const DateTime& dateTime)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto local_tp = local_days{year{dateTime.Year}/dateTime.Month/dateTime.Day} +
        hours{dateTime.Hour} + minutes{dateTime.Minute} + seconds{dateTime.Second};
    zoned_time zt{current_zone(), local_tp};
    return zt.get_sys_time();
}
```

You were on the right track with creating a `local_time` using `local_days`.

There's no need to explicitly name the `year_month_day` type.  This is generated for you using the `/` notation.

Once you have the local time, you can associate it with your computer's local time zone by constructing a `zoned_time` with `current_zone()` and the `local_time`.

Then you can extract the `sys_time` out of the `zoned_time`.  The `sys_time` is a `time_point<system_clock, seconds>` (seconds-precision `system_clock::time_point`), which is UTC (excluding leap seconds).  And this implicitly converts to the return type: `system_clock::time_point`.

If desired, you could interpret the `local_time` with respect to some other time zone, rather than your computer's local time zone.  For example:

```
    zoned_time zt{"America/New_York", local_tp};
```

In general, `zoned_time` is a convenience type used to translate between `local_time` and `sys_time`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice. I tried and tried and tried without finding the right way. I gave the `zoned_time` a go without success and here you come with this. However, the code is leaking memory and that is not due to my `_testee->GetDateTime()`. I get stuff like `Data: <America/New_York> 41 6D 65 72 69 63 61 2F 4E 65 77 5F 59 6F 72 6B` in my memory leak report. Anything I should care about somewhere?

Comment: I don't know for sure, because I don't have VS to experiment with, but my best guess is that this is a false memory leak report.  What is likely happening is that the `time_zone` for "America/New_York" is being created on demand, and lives as a singleton for the rest of your program.  `time_zone`s are somewhat like `type_info`s.  Their lifetimes are managed by the std::lib, and are non-copyable const singletons.

Comment: Yep, your theory seems to be confirmed by my local tests. Thanks for everything.